# Getting spaces while using :after and :before

Tags: css, pseudo-element

I'm using `:after` and `:before` pseudo-elements in my code to create an arrow like nav-bar. The code is working fine, apart from some extra spaces between the nav items. These spaces are because of `:after` and `:before` pseudo-elements. 
How can I remove the extra spaces?

```
.mat-tab-labels .mat-tab-label:after {
    content: "";
    border-top: 30px solid #f5f5f5;
    border-left: 30px solid #eee !important;
    height: 30px;
    border-bottom: 30px solid #f5f5f5;
  }
  .mat-tab-labels .mat-tab-label-active:after {
    content: "";
    border-top: 30px solid #f5f5f5;
    border-left: 30px solid #3c4650 !important;
    height: 30px;
    border-bottom: 30px solid #f5f5f5;
  }
  .mat-tab-labels .mat-tab-label:not(:first-child):before {
    content: "";
    border-top: 30px solid #eee;
    border-left: 30px solid #f5f5f5 !important;
    height: 30px;
    border-bottom: 30px solid #eee;
  }

  .mat-tab-labels .mat-tab-label-active:not(:first-child):before {
    content: "";
    border-top: 30px solid #3c4650 !important;
    border-left: 30px solid #f5f5f5 !important;
    height: 30px;
    border-bottom: 30px solid #3c4650 !important;
  }
```

Here is my Nav-bar HTML

```
<mat-tab-group>
        <mat-tab label="Marketing" class="mat-tab-label">
                    <div>Some code here</div>
        </mat-tab>
        <mat-tab label="Marketing" class="mat-tab-label">
                    <div>Some code here</div>
        </mat-tab>
        <mat-tab label="Marketing" class="mat-tab-label">
                    <div>Some code here</div>
        </mat-tab>
<mat-tab-group>
```

Comment: Absolute positioning of the pseudo elements? Negative margins? There’s a couple of approaches that could work.

Comment: Note that pseudo-elements should have **two colons** before them.  One colon indicates a pseudo-class.  Most browsers correct this mistake, but one shouldn't rely on that.

Answer (score 0):

You could add

```
.element {
    position:relative;
}

.element::before,
.element::after {
    position:absolute;
}
```

The required space can be adding by adding some padding on you .element.
Positioning the arrows should be done by top, left, bottom or right properties then.